# Multiple definition error in C++, using header files

Tags: c++, linker-errors, undefined-reference

im new to programming in C++, but have some experience with Java. Ive created a very basic class called Dog.cpp and its header file Dog.hpp. Netbeans will not build the project, giving me an error stating multiple definitions of both the constructor and the getAge function. As far as I am concerned I have declared the constructor and function in the header file, and defined them in the class file. Where have i gone wrong?

Thanks in advance!

**Dog.hpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Dog 
{
public:
    Dog(int someAge);           // Constructor
    ~Dog();                     // Destructor
    int getAge() const;         // function prototype
private:
    int itsAge;                 // age variable

};
```

**Dog.cpp:**

```
#include "Dog.hpp"
using namespace std;


Dog::Dog(int anAge) 
{
    cout << "Dog created \n";
}

int Dog::getAge() const
{
    return itsAge;
}
```

** main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Dog.cpp"

int main() 
{
    Dog aDog(5);
    cout << aDog.getAge();
    return 0;
}
```

Netbeans output:

```
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/david/NetBeansProjects/C++/SAMS - Hour 10'
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/sams_-_hour_10
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/david/NetBeansProjects/C++/SAMS - Hour 10'
mkdir -p build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86
rm -f build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o.d
g++    -c -g -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o.d -o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o main.cpp
mkdir -p build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86
rm -f build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/Dog.o.d
g++    -c -g -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/Dog.o.d -o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/Dog.o Dog.cpp
mkdir -p dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86
g++     -o dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/sams_-_hour_10 build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/Dog.o  
build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/Dog.o: In function `Dog::Dog(int)':
/home/david/NetBeansProjects/C++/SAMS - Hour 10/Dog.cpp:12: multiple definition of `Dog::Dog(int)'
build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o:/home/david/NetBeansProjects/C++/SAMS - Hour 10/Dog.cpp:12: first defined here
build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/Dog.o: In function `Dog::Dog(int)':
/home/david/NetBeansProjects/C++/SAMS - Hour 10/Dog.cpp:12: multiple definition of `Dog::Dog(int)'
build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o:/home/david/NetBeansProjects/C++/SAMS - Hour 10/Dog.cpp:12: first defined here
build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/Dog.o: In function `Dog::getAge() const':
/home/david/NetBeansProjects/C++/SAMS - Hour 10/Dog.cpp:18: multiple definition of `Dog::getAge() const'
build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o:/home/david/NetBeansProjects/C++/SAMS - Hour 10/Dog.cpp:18: first defined here
build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x6d): undefined reference to `Dog::~Dog()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x7f): undefined reference to `Dog::~Dog()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/sams_-_hour_10] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/david/NetBeansProjects/C++/SAMS - Hour 10'
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/david/NetBeansProjects/C++/SAMS - Hour 10'
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 931ms)
```

Comment: The header should have an include guard for one thing, but that wouldn't give these errors. Show a sample main file and build command. We cannot reproduce your problem with the information given.

Comment: For first, 2 suggestions, never put `using namespace` statements in header files and never put `using namespace` statements in header files!

Comment: Please edit your question to include the complete and unedited error log.

Comment: I'm guessing it's a problem in the build process, since the source code is fine (although header guards are a good idea, and you should not say `using` in a header).

Comment: I'll go with @chris probably a safe guard problem.

Comment: If you're going to employ a `using` directive in a header, you should encompass it in braces so it doesn't affect the code that includes it.

Comment: @40two, But that would cause multiple definitions of the class, not those functions.

Comment: @chris perhaps it does but the OP doesn't mention it.

Comment: @40two, Perhaps. If these are the only two source files other than the main one, it would need to include both of these for that to happen.

Comment: @chris you are the man! I want your magic crystal ball!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that you included the cpp module (Dog.cpp) with the member function definitions in the module with function main. You should include only headers.

Change Main.cpp the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Dog.hpp"

int main() 
{
    Dog aDog(5);
    cout << aDog.getAge();
    return 0;
}
```

Take into account that you forgot to set data member itsAge in the construtor. It should look as

```
Dog::Dog(int anAge) : itsAge( anAge )  
{
    cout << "Dog created \n";
}
```

And you forgot also to define the destructor.

You could write in the class definition for example the following way

```
class Dog 
{
public:
    Dog(int someAge);           // Constructor
    ~Dog() = default;           // Destructor
    int getAge() const;         // function prototype
private:
    int itsAge;                 // age variable

};
```

provided that the compiler supports this specifier.

Comment: Well, included and then linked to `dog.o`. That's my thinking. Just including the cpp would still only produce one definition (which I admit I sometimes take advantage of for school assignments so I can just compile and run one file generally from inside ST).

Comment: Judging from the updated question, this is exactly what was going on.

Comment: thanks Vlad, it would have taken ages to realise I had referenced the class file rather than the header :S

Answer (score 1):

Try doing either this in your 'Dog.hpp':

```c++
#ifndef HEADER_GUARD  // Top of file
#define HEADER_GUARD

/* Code in your class here. */

#endif  // End of file
```

Or this at top of the file:

```c++
#pragma once
```

The former block of code will tell the preprocessor to only include the code within the guard as long as the header guard definition ("FILENAME_HPP" for instance) is not defined. It immediately gets defined if that conditional passes, so the code should only be loaded once.

The latter block will also work - and possibly be more effective - on most compilers, including g++ and Visual C++. It tells the compiler to process the file only once.

Also, you seem to be missing a definition for your class's destructor.

Another Edit: One more thing, it is very bad programming practice to `#include` .cpp files. Always `#include` the header files that are associated with them.

Comment: thanks Dennis, the include .cpp was the problem, it was meant to include the header file instead, miss-typed it. I'll look into header guards for the future.